# How to select specific values based on each test cycles?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Now I have a raw data in SQL Server table which list the data transfer speed and device's temperature.

```
key           | value
－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－
test_unit     | AX45CG00598
speed_01      | 142.00
speed_02      | 138.00
speed_03      | 155.00
start_temp_01 | 31.04
start_temp_02 | 33.50
start_temp_03 | 33.88
end_temp_01   | 33.87
end_temp_02   | 34.29
end_temp_03   | 34.64
```

I want to select the values based on test cycles which the output will be like

```
test_unit   | cycle | speed  | start_temp | end_temp
－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－
AX45CG00598 | #01   | 142.00 | 31.04      | 33.87
AX45CG00598 | #02   | 138.00 | 33.50      | 34.29
AX45CG00598 | #03   | 155.00 | 33.88      | 34.64
```

Here is my code that output cycle and speed based on each cycles.

```
SELECT
  (select value from unnest(sql_server_table) where key = 'test_unit') as test_unit,
  case
    when key = 'speed_01' then '#01'
    when key = 'speed_02' then '#02'
    when key = 'speed_03' then '#03'
  end as cycle,
  props.value,
FROM
  unnest(sql_server_table) props
WHERE
  props.key in ('speed_01', 'speed_02', 'speed_03')
```

However, I have no idea how to list `temperature` also on the same row with `speed`.
Please advise, thank you.

Comment: What you are asking for is _not_ possible, not unless you have a third column for the test unit.

Comment: Are you sure you are using (Microsoft) SQL Server? Since when does it have an `unnest()` function? And why do you apply an `unnest()` function on a **table**? That is usually used to unnest arrays.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Oops, sorry, I forget to comment it is Google SQL.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Your data makes no sense unless you have a column that specifies the ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below example based on your sample data is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, [
    STRUCT<key STRING, value STRING>('test_unit', 'AX45CG00598'),
    ('speed_01', '142.00'),
    ('speed_02', '138.00'),
    ('speed_03', '155.00'),
    ('start_temp_01', '31.04'),
    ('start_temp_02', '33.50'),
    ('start_temp_03', '33.88'),
    ('end_temp_01', '33.87'),
    ('end_temp_02', '34.29'),
    ('end_temp_03', '34.64')
  ] props
)
SELECT id, 
  MAX(IF(key = 'test_unit', value, NULL)) test_unit, 
  '#' || cycle AS cycle,
  MAX(IF(key = 'speed_' || cycle, value, NULL)) speed, 
  MAX(IF(key = 'start_temp_' || cycle, value, NULL)) start_temp, 
  MAX(IF(key = 'end_temp_' || cycle, value, NULL)) end_temp  
FROM `project.dataset.table` t,
UNNEST(props) prop, 
UNNEST(['01', '02', '03']) cycle
GROUP BY id, cycle
```

with output

```
Row id  test_unit   cycle   speed   start_temp  end_temp     
1   1   AX45CG00598 #01     142.00  31.04       33.87    
2   1   AX45CG00598 #02     138.00  33.50       34.29    
3   1   AX45CG00598 #03     155.00  33.88       34.64
```